# How can I determine the size of an array?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

After a long search period, I was not able to figure out how to determine and use the `len` of an array like this:

```
\def\mar{ 1,2 }
\path let \p1=($(rec.west)-(rec.east)$),
              \p2=($(rec.north)-(rec.south)$),
              \p3=($len{\mar}$),
              \n1 = {veclen(\p1)*0.16}                  %width
              ,\n2 = {veclen(\p2)/\p3}                    %height
              in node[mynode,
                      minimum width=\n1
                      ,minimum height=\n2
                      ,anchor=north west
                      ] at (rec.north west) {foobar
                      };
```

Comment: `\p3` needs to be a `p`oint but you are assigning a number. Also as far as I know there is no array counter yet (Maybe in the CVS version). What exactly do you want to do with `\p3`?

Comment: I like to divide the height by the lenght of my array.

Comment: With TikZ/pgf, `\mar` is a simple list. An array should be defined by `\def{{1,2}}` (p.529, section 63.1, pgfmanual v2.10).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of any array length counter in TikZ (it might have been introduced in the CVS version). So getting some help from the [`xstring`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xstring) package, we count the commas and add one to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\mar{1,2,4,5,7}
\StrCount{\mar}{,}[\arrlength]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=5cm] (rec) at (2cm,1cm) {rec};
\path let \p1=($(rec.west)-(rec.east)$),
              \p2=($(rec.north)-(rec.south)$),
              \n{arrlen}={\arrlength+1},
              \n1 = {veclen(\p1)*0.16},           %width
              \n2 = {veclen(\p2)/\n{arrlen}}      %height
              in node[draw,
                      minimum width=\n1
                      ,minimum height=\n2
                      ,anchor=north west
                      ] at (rec.north west) {foobar
                      };
\end{tikzpicture}
I have found \arrlength\space commas in the array.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Like PolGab wrote in his comment, you have some possibilities to use an array with pgfmath. Here some examples from the pgfmanual :

> ```
> \def\myarray{{7,-3,4,-9,11}}
> \pgfmathparse{\myarray[3]} \pgfmathresult
>
> \def\print#1{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}
> \def\identitymatrix{{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}}
> \tikz[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]\foreach \i in {0,1,2} \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
>   \node at (\j,-\i) [anchor=base] {\print{\identitymatrix[\i][\j]}};
>
>   \pgfmathparse{array({9,13,17,21},2)} \pgfmathresult
> ```

Bad news :  `len` of an array does not exist in pgfmath. It's not very complex to add this possibility to pgfmath. Here a simple way without a new package. It's not very efficient but it's simple.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\def\getlen#1{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lenarray}{0}% 
\foreach \i in #1{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lenarray}{\lenarray+1}% 
\global\let\lenarray\lenarray}%
}   

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=5cm,fill=blue!30,opacity=.5 ] (rec) at (2cm,1cm) {REC};
    \def\mar{1,2}
    \getlen{\mar} 
\path let \p1=($(rec.west)-(rec.east)$),
          \p2=($(rec.north)-(rec.south)$),
          \n1 = {veclen(\p1)*0.16},
          \n2 = {veclen(\p2)/\lenarray}
              in node[draw,minimum width  = \n1,
                      minimum height = \n2,
                      anchor=north west,fill=orange!30,opacity=.5
                      ] at (rec.north west) {foobar};
  \end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems not to work with {10,20,...,180} construct? If I am correct how to make that work?

Comment: @MatthiasArras I think it's normal. {10,20,...,180} construct is useful with `\foreach` but here it's difficult to use

Comment: Oh yes it works as expected, I was under the impression that `\getlen` would return the number. But `\lenarray` does. So indeed `\getlen{{1,2,...,10}}\lenarray` works and outputs 10.

Answer (score 4):

The following uses a `\foreach` loop to count the number of members and ignores an empty members as the result of extraneous commas. So for a definition such as

```
\def\mar{1,2 , 4,, 5 ,7,,,}
```

this reports 5 members:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\mar{1,2 , 4,, 5 ,7,,,}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{@LengthOfArray}%
\newcommand{\GetArrayLength}{\arabic{@LengthOfArray}}%
\newcommand*{\SetArrayLength}[1]{%
    % Counts the number of array members. This ignore any empty
    % array members created by extraneous commas (such as those
    % as  result of a double comma, or a trailing comma.
    \setcounter{@LengthOfArray}{0}%
    \foreach \x in #1 {%
        \IfStrEq{\x}{}{}{% only increment when non-empty
            \stepcounter{@LengthOfArray}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\SetArrayLength{\mar}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=5cm] (rec) at (2cm,1cm) {rec};
\path let \p1=($(rec.west)-(rec.east)$),
              \p2=($(rec.north)-(rec.south)$),
              \n{arrlen}={\GetArrayLength},
              \n1 = {veclen(\p1)*0.16},           %width
              \n2 = {veclen(\p2)/\n{arrlen}}      %height
              in node[draw,
                      minimum width=\n1
                      ,minimum height=\n2
                      ,anchor=north west
                      ] at (rec.north west) {foobar
                      };
\end{tikzpicture}

\Large
There are \GetArrayLength\space members in the array.
\end{document}
```