# How to get the number of elements in a \foreach loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach

Does the PGF command `\foreach` provide a simple possibility to get the number of elements iterated?

It has a parameter `count` to hold the current element number, so a workaround is to iterate the list once. After execution, the last count is the number of elements in `#1`.

```
\foreach \letter [count=\n] in {#1} {}
% \n now keeps the number of elements.
```

Can this be achieved without iterating the whole list once?

Comment: So, are you actually asking how to obtain the length of a list? Your title (and first sentence of the body) suggest that you want to obtain it using `\foreach`. I suggest changing the title to something like: “Obtaining the length of a list in tikz-pgf”

Comment: Related Question: [How can I determine the size of an array?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66121/how-can-i-determine-the-size-of-an-array)

Comment: Note that "\n now keeps the number of elements" is a bug in TikZ which has been fixed in newer versions

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{dummy}
\def\getNoOfElements#1#2{%
  \setcounter{dummy}{0}% 
  \foreach\dummy in {#1}{\stepcounter{dummy}}%
  \edef#2{\arabic{dummy}}
}
\begin{document}

\getNoOfElements{a,b,c,d,e,f}\No % save the value in \No
\No

\getNoOfElements{1,2,3,4}\No
\No

\end{document}
```

Comment: From the original question: "Can this be achieved without iterating the whole list once?"

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to know the number of elements in a list without at least iterating the list once. I don't think you want the following tricks.

```
\def\procedure#1#2{%
%#1 comma separated elements
%#2 the number of elements in the list
\foreach \letter in {#1} {}%
% use the #2 here...
}
```

Comment: unless the array is indexed...

Comment: @percusse: Yes. But it is beyond the scope. :-)