# How can I draw an arrowhead only at the end of a path drawn with \foreach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach

I want to define a command for drawing some special polygonal lines with pgf/tikz. In these polygonal lines, the line styles are of alternating change. The following is my latex code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\drawline}[4][]{
  \foreach \v [remember=\v as \u,count=\i] in {#4} {
    \ifnum \i > 1
      \ifodd \i \draw[#1,#3] \u -- \v; \else \draw[#1,#2] \u -- \v; \fi
    \fi
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawline{solid,color=blue}{dashed,color=green}{(0,0),(1,1),(2,3),(5,5),(8,-1),(5,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output figure is as follows:

[image]

Now I want to add an arrow at the end of the polygonal line. How could I modify the above command definiton for this?

[image]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147544/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is draw an arrowhead only when you reach the last element.
Unfortunately, as discussed in [How to get the number of elements in a \foreach loop?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147544/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-foreach-loop), `\foreach` has no built-in mechanism to *a priori* determine the total number of elements that are passed to it; therefore, it has no way of detecting that it has reached the last element at the time it processes it.

You have two alternative approaches, here.

[image]

### 1 - Draw the path in reverse

Reverse the list you pass to `\foreach` (make the end point the start point) and draw an arrowhead only "at the beginning" (when `\i`=2).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\drawline}[4][]{
  \foreach \v [remember=\v as \u,count=\i] in {#4} {
    % draw an arrowhead only if we're processing the second element
    \ifnum \i = 2%
      \tikzset{tip/.style={<-}}%
    \else
      \tikzset{tip/.style={}}%
    \fi
    % the rest of your for loop
    \ifnum \i > 1%
      \ifodd \i%
        \draw[tip,#1,#3] \u -- \v;
      \else
        \draw[tip,#1,#2] \u -- \v;
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawline{solid,color=blue}{dashed,color=green}{(5,1),(8,-1),(5,5),(2,3),(1,1),(0,0)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### 2 - Count the total number of elements beforehand

Count the number of elements first, then set up a test in the body of your `\foreach` loop to detect whether the last element has been reached, and only draw an arrowhead in that case.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcount\foreachNumel

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\drawline}[4][]{
  % count the number of elements in #4
  \global\foreachNumel=0%
  \foreach \v in {#4}
    {\global\advance\foreachNumel by \@ne}
  \foreach \v [remember=\v as \u,count=\i] in {#4} {
    % draw an arrowhead only if we're processing the last element
    \ifnum \i = \foreachNumel%
      \tikzset{tip/.style={->}}%
    \else
      \tikzset{tip/.style={}}%
    \fi
    % the rest of your for loop
    \ifnum \i > 1%
      \ifodd \i%
        \draw[tip,#1,#3] \u -- \v;
      \else
        \draw[tip,#1,#2] \u -- \v;
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawline{solid,color=blue}{dashed,color=green}{(0,0),(1,1),(2,3),(5,5),(8,-1),(5,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Possibly overkill and arguably less efficient than iterating over a list of points using `\foreach`, but the following `polyline` decoration (I think) is an almost complete generalization of the requirements for an arbitrary number of styles.

Note it may fail with paths less than `.1pt` in length.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\newcount\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcount
\pgfdeclaredecoration{polyline}{start}{
\state{start}[width=0pt,
  next state=draw,
  persistent precomputation={\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcount=1}]{}
\state{draw}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength,
  switch if less than=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+.1pt to final,
  persistent postcomputation={\advance\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcount by1}]
{
  \pgfcoordinate{@1}{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentfirst}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@2}{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
  \let\i=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcount%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\i{int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/polyline style function})}%
  \ifnum\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcount=1\relax%
    \path [/pgf/decoration/every polyline/.try, 
      /pgf/decoration/polyline 1/.try, 
      /pgf/decoration/polyline first/.try]
      (@1) -- (@2) \pgfdecorationpolylinenodes;
  \else%
    \path [/pgf/decoration/every polyline/.try, 
      /pgf/decoration/polyline \i/.try]
      (@1) -- (@2) \pgfdecorationpolylinenodes;
  \fi%
}
\state{final}{
  \pgfcoordinate{@1}{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentfirst}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@2}{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
  \let\i=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcount%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\i{int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/polyline style function})}%
  \path [/pgf/decoration/every polyline/.try, 
    /pgf/decoration/polyline \i/.try, 
    /pgf/decoration/polyline last/.try]
     (@1) -- (@2) \pgfdecorationpolylinenodes;
}
}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
  polyline style function/.initial=\i}
\tikzset{%
  polyline nodes/.store in=\pgfdecorationpolylinenodes,
  polyline nodes=,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[polyline label/.style={
  circle, inner sep=1pt, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, fill=black!75, text=white,
}]
\path 
[decoration={polyline,
  polyline style function={mod(\i-1,7)+1},
  polyline 1/.style={draw=red},
  polyline 2/.style={draw=yellow},
  polyline 3/.style={draw=pink},
  polyline 4/.style={draw=green},
  polyline 5/.style={draw=orange},
  polyline 6/.style={draw=purple},
  polyline 7/.style={draw=blue},
  polyline last/.style={-stealth},
  every polyline/.style={ultra thick, 
    polyline nodes={node [midway, transform shape, polyline label] {\i}}
  }}, decorate]
  (0,0) \foreach \i in {1,...,28}{
    -- ++(rand*180-90:rnd*1+2)
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]