# Trouble parsing array with single item

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I am trying to parse arrays of strings, but when I create an array of containing a single string (say the string contains n characters), it is not parsed correctly, instead it's parsed as containing n items, with each item an individual character. can anyone shed some light on why does this happen? thanks in advance! Code and output below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\begin{document}

\noindent Array 1 is \{"this","is","cool"\}

\def\myArray{{"this","is","cool"}}

\pgfmathparse{dim(\myArray)}
\edef\myArrayLength{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\myArrayLength-1}
\edef\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} 
{
  \noindent Array 1, item \i: \pgfmathparse{\myArray[\i]}\pgfmathresult \newline
}

\noindent Array 2 is \{"not cool"\}

\def\singleItemArray{{"not cool"}}

\pgfmathparse{dim(\singleItemArray)}
\edef\singleItemArrayLength{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\singleItemArrayLength-1}
\edef\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} 
{
  \noindent Array 2, item \i: \pgfmathparse{\singleItemArray[\i]}\pgfmathresult \newline
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, there is no formal definition for arrays, just a few examples. It's not the space, because `{{"notcool"}}` produces the same issue. Length one arrays seem to be invalid, as `{{12}}` turns out to have length two as well.

Comment: To work around this bug/feature, you can enclose each element into braces:  `\def\myArray{{{"this"},{"is"},{"cool"}}}`, `\def\myArray{{{"not cool"}}}`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with an other array length command and some if...else statements to handle the single item arrays, which are causing problems.

**Step 1:** Compute the size of an array with [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66159/124842) by @[Alain Matthes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes)

```
\def\getlen#1{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lenarray}{0}% 
\foreach \i in #1{%
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lenarray}{\lenarray+1}% 
 \global\let\lenarray\lenarray}%
}
```

> *Example:* define array `\def\mar{1,2}`,compute length `\getlen{\mar}` and get value `\lenarray %=> '2'`

***Note:*** length of the array is stored in `\r` with `\edef\r{\lenarray}`.

**Step 2:** Expand the single array:

```
\ifnum\r=1
\def\myArray{{\myArrayRoh,"\relax "}}
\else
\def\myArray{{\myArrayRoh}}
\fi
```

**Step 3:**  ... so you have to reduce the last item index with `2` instead of `1` for every single array:

```
\ifnum\r=1
\pgfmathparse{\myArrayLength-2} % single item
\else
\pgfmathparse{\myArrayLength-1} % multiple items
\fi
```

**Result:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66159/124842 (@Alain Matthes)
\def\getlen#1{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lenarray}{0}% 
\foreach \i in #1{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lenarray}{\lenarray+1}% 
\global\let\lenarray\lenarray}%
}   
\begin{document}
\def\myArrayRoh{"this"} % singleItemArray

\getlen{\myArrayRoh} 
\edef\r{\lenarray}

\ifnum\r=1
    \def\myArray{{\myArrayRoh,"\relax "}}
\else
    \def\myArray{{\myArrayRoh}}
\fi
%    
\pgfmathparse{dim(\myArray)}
\edef\myArrayLength{\pgfmathresult}

\ifnum\r=1
\pgfmathparse{\myArrayLength-2}
\else
\pgfmathparse{\myArrayLength-1}
\fi

\edef\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} 
{
  \noindent Array 1, item \i: \pgfmathparse{\myArray[\i]}\pgfmathresult \newline
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\myArrayRoh{"this","is","cool"} % multiItemArray

\getlen{\myArrayRoh} 
\edef\r{\lenarray}

\ifnum\r=1
    \def\myArray{{\myArrayRoh,"\relax "}}
\else
    \def\myArray{{\myArrayRoh}}
\fi

\pgfmathparse{dim(\myArray)}
\edef\myArrayLength{\pgfmathresult}

\ifnum\r=1
\pgfmathparse{\myArrayLength-2}
\else
\pgfmathparse{\myArrayLength-1}
\fi

\edef\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} 
{
  \noindent Array 2, item \i: \pgfmathparse{\myArray[\i]}\pgfmathresult \newline
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey @Bobyandbob - very nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use xstring for a simple string item or listofitems for separated items:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}


{\bfseries xstring on list:}\vspace{10pt}

\def\myarray{not cool}
\StrLen{\myarray}[\MyStrLen]

Items of "\myarray": \MyStrLen\par
\foreach \i in {1,...,\MyStrLen}{Item \i: ``\StrMid{\myarray}{\i}{\i}''\par}\vspace*{20pt}

{\bfseries listofitems on list:}\vspace{10pt}

\setsepchar{,}
\def\mylist{test item, {another item}, third item}
\readlist\commalist\mylist

Items of "\mylist":\commalistlen\par
\foreachitem\x\in\commalist{Item \xcnt: ``\x''\par}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit after comment:**

For one item list, `listofitems` is still an option.

Adding the follow code on the above file:

```
\setsepchar{,}
\def\mylist{"not cool"}
\readlist\commalist\mylist

Items of "\mylist":\commalistlen\par
\foreachitem\x\in\commalist{Item \xcnt: ``\x''\par}\vspace{20pt}
```

We get the desired result:

[image]

PS: There is a problem if we enclose the item inside `{}` that I thing have to be reported to maintainer.

Comment: Aren't you missing the point here? The idea is to *not* parse the second one char by char. I think adding answers about a related issue just in case someone find this in a search while looking for something else is a bad idea.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right. But I wasn't really off topic. I just gave a solution on such problems (more for newbies). I edited and added an one item list parsed with `listofitems`... I still thing this is not the answer that the OP is looking for, but solves such problems (of pursing an one item list-array). I just found an error of the package that I will report to the maintainer so, that the list can be read exactly as the OP is giving it.

Comment: The maintainer of `listofitems` (@Christian Tellechea) just informed me that he will try to fix the bug as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a bug of PGF, as there's no formal definition of what an array is; but it turns out that an array *must not* have length one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\begin{document}

\verb|\def\myArray{{"this","is","cool"}}|
\def\myArray{{"this","is","cool"}}

\pgfmathsetmacro\myArrayLength{dim(\myArray)}

\pgfmathsetmacro\lastIndex{\myArrayLength-1}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} 
 {
  Array 1, item \i: \pgfmathparse{\myArray[\i]}\pgfmathresult\par
 }

\verb|\def\myArray{{"notcool"}}|
\def\myArray{{"notcool"}}

\pgfmathsetmacro\myArrayLength{dim(\myArray)}

\pgfmathsetmacro\lastIndex{\myArrayLength-1}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} 
 {
  Array 2, item \i: \pgfmathparse{\myArray[\i]}\pgfmathresult\par
 }

\verb|\def\myArray{{12}}|
\def\myArray{{12}}

\pgfmathsetmacro\myArrayLength{dim(\myArray)}

\pgfmathsetmacro\lastIndex{\myArrayLength-1}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} 
 {
  Array 3, item \i: \pgfmathparse{\myArray[\i]}\pgfmathresult\par
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

The last example gives the same result as with `\def\myArray{{1,2}}`.